# Tortoise ORM - Pydantic model with Postgresql time field

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to create a Pydantic model with Tortoise ORM with Postgresql as the backend. I have the columns `start_time` and `end_time` defined in Postgres as a Time datatype. I tried my class as below:

```
class Carb_Ratio(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True, auto_generated=True)
    client_id = fields.UUIDField()
    ratio_type = fields.CharEnumField(RatioType)
    carb_ratio = fields.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    start_time = fields.CharField(max_length=8)
    end_time = fields.CharField(max_length=8)
    insulin_sensitivity = fields.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When i try to create a record i end up with an error message "tortoise.exceptions.OperationalError: invalid input for query argument $5: '' ('str' object has no attribute 'hour')"

Tortoise fields do not have a TimeField, I tried even with fields.DatetimeField gives me an invalid datetime format for "08:00:00"

Any pointers in the right direction would be of help. Thanks in advance

Update:
@Adrian Klaver thank you for your suggestion.
I've changed these fields to DatetimeField

```
    start_time = fields.DatetimeField()
    end_time = fields.DatetimeField()
```

my input values has to be changed from

```
{
  "client_id": "9181233d-0fa3-4844-bb28-ba1660be1415",
  "ratio_type": "time_range",
  "carb_ratio": 16,
  "start_time": "17:00:01",
  "end_time": "21:00:00",
  "insulin_sensitivity": 6
}
```

to

```
{
  "client_id": "9181233d-0fa3-4844-bb28-ba1660be1415",
  "ratio_type": "time_range",
  "carb_ratio": 16,
  "start_time": "1900-01-01 17:00:01",
  "end_time": "1900-01-01 21:00:00",
  "insulin_sensitivity": 6
}
```

and now it is able to insert values properly. However the select function now errors with "iso8601.iso8601.ParseError: Expecting a string datetime.time(10, 0)"

Comment: You need to add to your question the part in the code where you create/assign the value to argument `$5`.  Best guess is you are assuming you are working with a `datetime.time` object when you are in fact you are working with a `str` object.

Comment: If the Postgres field are still of `time` type then your changes to the model type and the input values will not work. `"1900-01-01 17:00:01"` is not a valid time format.